# Updating Dead Link Answer with Cached LInk

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, broken-link

As per the title really, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20404831/2075402) which is pretty much link only. The link appears to be dead but there is a cached version of the page [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://phuse.ca/the-best-way-to-vertically-align-in-css/&gws_rd=cr&ei=yX5KVdKBA-rG7Abcl4HIAQ).

Is it acceptable to edit the answer with a cached link?

As the answer is pretty much link only, if it's acceptable to edit the link, is it worth grabbing the code from the cached page and updating the answer with it and a couple of pointers to address the comment regarding the answer?

Comment: Looking at that answer and the others this link can be missed. I wouldn't bother editing. I flagged it for LQ.

Comment: I'd say that if you replace a link, then you should link to archive.org. The entry in the google cache might be removed as well eventually (and probably sooner rather than later).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since the answer is, as you say, pretty much link-only, it's probably not worth fixing since it won't solve the problem of having a bad post and in the end will just encourage the user to keep posting the link-only answers since they'll keep getting upvotes and rep.

I'd say that the better solution would be to post another answer with the correct information if you think you can provide something that the already accepted answer does not.

Comment: Thanks, I'm no master at CSS so I'm not in a position to answer but will raise a flag for being LQ rather than editing.